# Topology - Basis

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a set, and let $\mathcal{B}$ be a basis for some topology $\tau$ on $X$ and let $A$ be a subset of $X$.

show

> $x\in\textrm{cl}(A)$ if and only if for every $ C \in \mathcal{B} $ containing $ x,$ $\big(C\cap A\neq \emptyset\big).$

I tried to show this by contrapositive but I failed. Any Hints please?

Comment: For the harder direction: If $U$ is open and contains $x$, you want to show $U$ meets $A$. There is a basis element $B$ containing $x$ and contained in $U$. So ...

Comment: If x is not in Cl(A), then there exists C a closed set such that A is subset of C. So x is not in  C. This implies that x is in X-C which is an
open set. A being a subset C implies that (X - C) intersect A is empty. Right? Thats one direction

Comment: Since you are working with open sets rather than closed sets, try using this characterization of the closure:
$$x\in\textrm{cl}(A) \iff \forall U\in\tau \, \big((U\subseteq A^{c}) \Rightarrow (x\notin U)\big).$$

Comment: I have another question where i feel like i m missing something. How do we know that X-C is in the basis B?

Answer (score 3):

If $x\in cl(A)$ then $U\cap A\neq\emptyset$ for any open set $U$ that contains $x$ and sets in the basis are indeed open sets.

If $x\notin cl(A)$ then $x\in cl(A)^c$ wich is an open set. Then $x\in C\subset cl(A)^c$ for some $C$ that belongs to the basis. Then $C\cap A=\emptyset$.